# What is the cause of these round holes in my yard, potentially snakes?

Tags: identification, lawn, pest-control, pests

I noticed round holes in my lawn over the last few days. My neighbor thinks they are snake holes. He is just taking a wild guess per his own admission. I am in Maryland and we have had a lot of rain in the last few days.

[image][image]

Comment: How deep are they?  They look like squirrels digging up their nuts to me.

Answer (score 2):

Snakes use old tunnels of moles and shrews and gophers.  There is no sign of digging for this hole so it just might be a snake.  Snakes are usually totally beneficial and take care of mice, rats, voles that might do damage to your plants.  The snakes are not going to be a problem.

Moles and gophers aren't a problem.

But your lawn could us some help.  What time of year is it where you live?  Where do you live?

Comment: I have snakes ( I don't kill them ) and never saw a hole made by a snake. They use existing holes if any at all.

Answer (score 0):

Voles. That's what is causing these. Need to get some critter control help. The grass is also in bad shape because of that.

Comment: Voles might be a 'user' of already made tunnels, sure. But they did not MAKE these holes. Do you see any sign of freshly dug up soil?

Comment: Wait.  This lawn is in no way being harmed by any tiny soil digging tunneling mammals.  Moles, voles, gophers...these mammals are wonderful to have aerating and top dressing lawns, plant beds.  They eat GRUBS  Usually larvae of insects that do harm plants, grass crowns.  Critter control or critter killing never ever helps...I wouldn't want to get rid of the one maybe two moles, or shrews, or gophers making tunnels.  They do incredible work with the soil, leave them alone so they are able to work FOR you.  That grass is not maintained correctly, and we can teach the owner proper maintenance.

Comment: Sorry, but these little guys DO not harm lawns or plants unless they are starving.  I used to charge people big bucks to do what these guys do for free.  That hole is not made by a tunneling critter, it might be in use by an opportunist such as a snake but there is absolutely no sign of recent digging.  When we insist on total control we get in huge trouble.  Harmony among those that were already here before us humans and the native flora and what we insist we need for food or ornamentation takes getting used to but works beautifully.  Integrated life management?

Answer (score 0):

Yes moles do do harm to grass The tunnels and the dirt that is left behind from digging covers grass which kills it. If you have spent a lot of money on keeping your lawn nice and presentable this is a waste of your money. Getting rid of moles is an option to keep your yard from looking mangled. if you're concerned about aeration then have a company do aeration once a year typically at the end of the fall but we got rid of our moles with a critter control company and it lasted for a couple of years.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely soil-subsidence.   You can find a picture that looks exactly like yours on this website:  https://www.walterreeves.com/insects-and-animals/diagnosing-holes-in-the-yard/

What differentiates subsidence holes & critter holes is the presence of loose dirt - which occurs with critter made holes.

Comment: That size seems a bit small for subsidence? And perhaps even a tad too neat?

Answer (score -1):

Squirrels dig holes to smell for there nuts I have tons of grey squirrels and holes just like yours.